# How to remotely control Android device?

Tags: android, remote-access

Is there any application for Android that let me see and control customers' Android devices (like TeamViewer on Windows)? I can Image it as a client-server application.

I published an application for Android and customer service needs to see what the customer sees on their screen. Sometimes they need to take control of customer's device to make some changes.

1. The client app must run Android 2.3 or later
2. The client app need to be free to install and use
3. Server application can be run from Windows, Android or web
4. Need to see what user see on the device
5. Better if I can take control of the device (touch screen, folder & files..)
6. Don't need a rooted device

Answer (score 5):

To my knowledge, in order to run some VNC server or equivalent on Android, you must root it. As a free VNC server, you can use [droid VNC server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.onaips.vnc):

- Free (and open-source)
- Android 1.6 and up
- Allow to see what user see on the device
- Allow to take control of the device (Mouse & Kb emulation)
- Password authentication
- Clipboard support

Client-side you just need a standard VNC Viewer (I use RealVNC).

Comment: Ok, I add the 6th point to my question. Thank you.

Comment: @Seraphim'shost VNC was also what I had in mind. If this app doesn't satisfy you (but the principle is OK), there are [several alternative VNC servers available](http://www.appbrain.com/search?q=vnc%20server) :)

Comment: Do you need to be on the users LAN to use this? I've used other VNC programs in the past and you needed to remote into a computer on their network before you could use this.

Comment: @Chillie users just need to be able to access each other's IP

Comment: App has been pulled from the Play Store for what I'm guessing no longer working in recent versions of Android.  https://github.com/oNaiPs/droidVncServer

Answer (score 5):

I found that Teamviewer has a mobile app, known as TeamViewer QuickSupport. It looks like it meets your requirements.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teamviewer.quicksupport.market

EDIT: I gave it a try and this is what it does.

1. Requires Android 2.3.3+
2. The client is free. (The server is free for "Personal" use)
3. Server can be run from Windows, Mac, or Linux.
4. User can send screenshots to the host, but only some devices have the capability to be remote controlled (see below), but I'm not sure. On my Samsung S4 (Android 4.3) I was able to remote control.
5. See 4.
6. Does not need rooted.

---

**Additional Info for bullets 4 & 5.**

What I found is that the QuickSupport App does everything except remote control. Then, each individual client downloads an additional package that is specific to their manufacturer. For instance, I had to download the Samsung pack. The client is prompted to do so, so there isn't any hunting around for the right app, so it is fairly easy.

For the full list of support packs, click [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=TeamViewer).

Currently, it appears as if other brands (Motorola, HTC, Sony) are not supported (yet), but they might be available through one of the (many) Prestigio packs, i'm not sure, you will have to test that.

Comment: Have you tried it? What are your experiences? What are the Pros and Cons of this app, why is it recommendable? Please [read our discussion on what makes an answer high quality](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185) to see if you can incorporate some of these improvements into your answer.

Comment: I have not tried it since I only found it through an internet search.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to be editing this answer as I find more options and info.  I have been using something called [Alpha VNC Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.abr.android.avnc).  Unfortunately DroidVNC no longer works in 7.0 at least for me.  Alpha VNC lite doesn't seem to work on the home screen but most other apps seem to work fine.  The device doesn't need to be rooted but you do not to enable a special keyboard and accessibility options.  It requires Android 5.0 and up.  If you just want to see the screen but don't care about controlling you can use [TeamViewer QuickSupport](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teamviewer.quicksupport.market).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at [droidVNC-NG](https://github.com/bk138/droidVNC-NG), which is an Android VNC server using contemporary Android 5+ APIs, therefore not requiring root access.

It's open-source (GPL-2) (I wrote it) and already usable to fully remote-control an Android device via mouse pointer. Keyboard handling is still work in progress. Contributions for further improvements very welcome.