# Android screencast video recorder that doesn't need root

Tags: android, video

I am looking for an Android screencast video recorder that doesn't need root (e.g. unlike the [Screencast Video Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ms.screencastfree) app). If possible, free and HD. I use a Samsung Galaxy S3 if the application is device-dependent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, what you want is not possible for security reasons -- that's why everything needs root.

On an Android 4.4+ device, you can [use `screenrecord` via **`adb`**](https://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#screenrecord). This is time-limited to a maximum of three minutes and will not record audio.

For devices with HDMI capability, you can use try hardware HDMI recorders.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed answer! I indeed thought that wouldn't be possible for security reason, but then I saw http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/2484/903 which claims Teamviewer has a way to do remote control using an additional package that is specific to their manufacturer, so I was wondering whether there are way around it.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt: Certain devices may have additional screen recording capabilities, whether using Teamviewer or their own "secret sauce". Likewise, certain ROM mods might have their own stuff for this.