# Samsung Smart TV - How to remotely control and view screen

Tags: remote-control

I'm looking for a TeamViewer-like solution for a Samsung SmartTV (Tizen-based).

**Motivation:** My elderly mother constantly gets lost in the SmartTV menus, and it's incredibly hard and frustrating to guide her over the phone.

**Requirements:**

- Must control The following SmartTV function: Switch input (to cable input), operate Netflix, operate YouTube, operate custom app ([כאן BOX](https://www.kan.org.il/lists/item.aspx?itemid=33828))
- Must be always on to receive command from a client (who has the password). Can't require the end-user to click *anything*
- Can be operated from at least one of: PC, Android phone.

**Non-Solutions:**

- [Samsung Remote Access](https://www.samsung.com/latin_en/support/tv-audio-video/how-to-use-the-remote-access-on-your-samsung-smart-tv/) - This lets you control a PC *from* a SmartTV
- [TeamViewer QuickSupport](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teamviewer.quicksupport.market) (from [question here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2468/how-to-remotely-control-android-device), [TeamViewer discussion](https://community.teamviewer.com/English/discussion/109667/how-to-download-and-install-team-viewer-on-samsung-smart-tv)) - works for Android only, AFAIK Samsung SmartTVs don't run Android, but Tizen ([source](https://www.knowyourmobile.com/user-guides/samsung-tvs-do-not-run-android-heres-why/))
- [Android App - TV Remote for Samsung TV](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=smart.tv.wifi.remote.control.samcontrol&hl=en) - this assumes you're in front of the TV, which I am not...
- Security camera pointed at the screen - if I can't find a software solution, I may end up doing this...